# How to set multiple start and end time in single string

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I want to save multiple start and end time with comma separated in database.

For example following is my array of start time and end time.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1:00
    [1] => 2:00
    [2] => 3:00
    [3] => 4:00
)
```

I want to store it into database like `1:00-2:00, 3:00-4:00` .

How can i do this ?

I used following code for it.

```
$array = array('1:00','2:00','3:00','4:00');
$i=0;
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if($i%2 !=0){
        echo $value.'-'.',';
    }
    echo $value.'-';

$i++;
}
```

Comment: Show us your efforts

Comment: You do this by writing code. Although you really should not do this as it will make data retrieval unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used array_chunk and do the 2 foreach loop, I don't know it's correct format My Code is:

```
$array = array('1:00','2:00','3:00','4:00');
$i=0;
$input_array = array_chunk($array, 2);
foreach ($input_array as $key => $value) {
  foreach($value as $val){      
    if($i%2 != 0){
        echo $val.',';
    }else{
     echo $val.'-';
    }
    $i++;
  }
}
```

O/P is:

```
1:00-2:00,3:00-4:00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array = array('1:00','2:00','3:00','4:00');
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if($i%2 == 0){
        $start = $value;
    } else {
        $end = $value;
        if($output != "") $output .= ",";
        $output .= $start . "-" . $end;
    }
$i++;
}

echo $output;
?>
```

So a quick walk through of what I have done.

I have removed your `$i` variable as this will be identical to your `$key` value in your loop.

The `$start` variable is your start time and the `$end` is your end time `$start-$end`

We check if `$output` exists so we know whether to put a comma or not first - you don't want the comma on the before the first number but you do for numbers thereafter.

This is the output of the above script:

```
1:00-2:00,3:00-4:00
```